# Ruby on Rails - REGEX on where Model query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, search

I have this method to make a search

```
def self.search(search)
  where("titulo LIKE ?", "([a-zA-Z0-9]*)[ X]*#{search}")
end
```

Right now doesn't recognize anything. I suspect it isn't recognizing the REGEX.

But i can't find any answers to how to use regex in the where clause

Does someone know?

Answer (score 2):

**Postgresql**

The keyword for using regexp in Postgresql is `SIMILAR TO`.

```
def self.search(search)
  where("titulo SIMILAR TO ?", "([a-zA-Z0-9]*)[ X]*#{search}")
end
```

**Mysql**

If you're using Mysql then the keyword is `REGEXP`.

```
def self.search(search)
  where("titulo REGEXP ?", "([a-zA-Z0-9]*)[ X]*#{search}")
end
```

It would be nice to know what you're trying to do if you want better answers and maybe help with your regular expression. For instance, what are the results you're expecting, etc...